# Android Game Background

Tags: android, background, bitmap

So I'm working on developing a game for a school project and so far its gone well, but I have been trying to use a bitmap image instead of just using drawColor for the background, but doing so has make the game sluggish, not respond to to Touch Events, and ultimately crash after a while. Here is my code so far for making that background that keeps crashing, I am using the getColor before the drawBitmap as to blank out the previous background, because without that the moving character threads were leaving a "trail" and not being erased after every movement.

```
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap
    (BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.park),0,0,null);
```

So any more effective method to make a static background image for the thread to move over would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is that you are loading your bitmap everytime you're rendering, which is why it runs slow and crashes after a while because of memory constraints. You should load your image once when you initialize everything:

```
// run once when you start the game
Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.park);
```

In your render code:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(background);
```

And don't forget too free the image when you're done with it:

```
background.recycle();
```

Comment: I always had issues with understanding the term "done with it"... When is this supposed to happen? Can you give an example Durza, if you have the time.

Comment: @JoxTraex With "done with it" I mean when you don't need the image anymore, for example if you have different levels with different backgrounds in your game then you want to recycle the background image which you're not going to use anymore, to free up memory.

Comment: I see, I had a feeling that was the use case. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Durza007 Thanks! Game is running great now

Answer (score 0):

The reason your application is slowing down is you are keeping too many references to the same bitmap and this is consuming the amount of memory that you have available, you need to release images as you dont need them. There a bunch of videos by Romain Guy on graphics and game graphics. Look on youtube and you'll learn how to handle this problem.